# Как создать ось QAbstractAxis

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyqt

Рисую свечной график на pyqt5.
Если по оси X использовать значения по дефолту, то на каждом элементе будут значения, что загромождает график и все сливается, то есть нет возможности регулировать "setTickCount", как в других типах осей.
Но, если создать отдельно ось "axisX = QDateTimeAxis()", то будут пустые промежутки в выходные дни(пример в коде).
Мне посоветовали создать "QLineSeries()" создать в ней ось "QDateTimeAxis()", а сам линейный график скрыть а ось оставить, на свечном графике создать ось "axisX = QValueAxis()" и скрыть ее.
Визуально выглядит все нормально, но при проверке видно, что ось Х не совпадает с самим свечным графиком.

Есть еще один способ создать массив string на основе DateTime и использовать для оси X [QAbstractAxis](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractaxis.html).  Но, по этому виду оси очень мало примеров и не понятно, как ее применить.

Файл с данными находится здесь [Файл](https://dropmefiles.com/vo5PI)

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtChart
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtChart import *
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file_string.txt',
                 index_col='DATE',
                 parse_dates=True,
                 infer_datetime_format=True)

date = df.iloc[:, 0].index.date
o = df.iloc[:, 0].values
h = df.iloc[:, 1].values
l = df.iloc[:, 2].values
z = df.iloc[:, 3].values
x = len(z)
x_ = x - 2

qt = [None] * x

for i in range(0, x):
   qt[i] = QDateTime(date[i]).toMSecsSinceEpoch()

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.step = 30
        self._chart_view = QtChart.QChartView()
        self.scrollbar = QtWidgets.QScrollBar(
            QtCore.Qt.Horizontal,
            sliderMoved=self.onAxisSliderMoved,
            pageStep=self.step,
        )

        self.scrollbar.setRange(0, x_)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        for w in (self._chart_view, self.scrollbar):
            lay.addWidget(w)

        self._chart = QtChart.QChart()
        self._candlestick_serie = QtChart.QCandlestickSeries()


        for i in range(0, len(z)):
            o_ = o[i]
            h_ = h[i]
            l_ = l[i]
            c_ = z[i]
            self._candlestick_serie.append(QtChart.QCandlestickSet(o_, h_, l_, c_, qt[i]))

        min_x, max_x = 0, x_

        self._chart.addSeries(self._candlestick_serie)
        self._chart.legend().hide()
        self._chart_view.setChart(self._chart)
        self.lims = np.array([min_x, max_x])

        axisX = QDateTimeAxis()
        axisX.setTickCount(5)
        axisX.setFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
        self._chart.addAxis(axisX, Qt.AlignBottom)
        self._candlestick_serie.attachAxis(axisX)

        axisY = QValueAxis()
        self._chart.addAxis(axisY, Qt.AlignLeft)
        self._candlestick_serie.attachAxis(axisY)

        self.onAxisSliderMoved(self.scrollbar.value())
        self.adjust_axes(0, 31)

    def adjust_axes(self, value_min, value_max):
        if value_min >= 0 and value_max > 0 and value_max <= x_ and value_max > value_min:
            self._chart.axisX(self._candlestick_serie).setRange(QDateTime(date[value_min]), QDateTime(date[value_max]))


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def onAxisSliderMoved(self, value):
        value2 = value + self.step
        value1 = value
        if value2 >= x_:
            value2 = x_
            value1 = value2 - self.step
        self.adjust_axes(math.floor(value1), math.ceil(value2))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1105942/pyqtchart-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%88%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%81%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5/1106547#1106547 ?

Comment: Это не то. Ограничить диапазон для показа могу. Нужно, чтобы по оси х было время, но без пропусков в выходные дни(значения баров в выходные отсутствуют, а ось QDateTimeAxis() на них есть, поэтому пустые промежутки). В C# сделал так: преобразовал datetime в string и отобразил эти данные по оси. Кажется это правильно называется переопределить метки к оси.  Вот здесь мне подсказали варианты: [https://qtcentre.org/threads/71209-Number-of-tick-marks-on-the-axis-in-QBarCategoryAxis?p=308658&highlight=#post308658]   Все попробовал остался только с абстрактной осью.

Comment: Попробуйте задать вопрос на https://stackoverflow.com/ , но отформатируйте текст так, чтобы он был визуально понятен и  данные `file_string.txt` должен быть представлен в вопросе, а не ссылке.